# Connecting a 'sent' SMS to a 'received' SMS

Tags: sms, sid

I have built an app that sends out an SMS using the twilio number(the one assigned to me) when a message is sent I receive the SID number which is inserted into the db, along with some other general information, however I do not know how to connect the received SMS SID to the sent SMS SID that tells the system that user has responded....how does someone connect the outgoing message to what is received?

UPDATE:
Hello Devin, Thanks for the response! however, this does not help me much as I might send lets say one of three different people multiple messages in an hour.

my app is a notification app...basically it is a form that a user fills out with some basic info.  one of these fileds they choose is a drop down of three different people(who the message will go to) they send the message.  my app then inserts the form data explained above along with the SMSID that is returned by you guys into a DB.

the user(one of the three people descibed above) that was sent the notification above responds to the message, meaning that Twilio hits my "Request URL" and I save all the information that is returned by the user...however, and where the problem actually lies is that the SMSID for that reply is not the same as the SMSID of the sent notification...therefore I have no way to connect the SMS that was sent to the user with their response.  I have looked at the cookies option and that is not what I am needing...actually your documentation actually acknowledges this issue but does not offer a solution as seen here under "Application Initiated Conversations"

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html

So if you know of a way around this, I would love to hear it for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The SMS protocol has no concept of a "conversation".  Each message sent is unique and has no knowledge of messages sent before or after it.  Twilios SMS Sid is simply a unique identifier for an individual message.

The typical way to solve this is to use the To/From phone number pair as the unique identifier of an SMS conversation.  When you send your first outbound message, store the To/From phone number in your database.  When the user replies Twilio will tell you what number they sent the message to  and from and you can use that information to look up the original outbound message in your database.

If a "user" can be involved in several different conversations at once you either need to use a unique phone number for each seperate conversation (allowing you to use the technique above), or you need to have the user include some type of conversation ID in their reply (which you can use as the unique identifier).

You can buy a pool of numbers and as each conversation "ends", recycle the number for a new conversation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Devin, can you check out my original post under UPDATE, the comment section here would not let me the entire message.